# How to add an arow button in horizontal scrollview

Tags: android

![this is the example which done in ipad.
i want similar to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJXvX.jpg)I have a horizontal scrollview, in this view i want to add a transparent arrow image denoting scroll and it should be invisible when the scroll works. But it should visible when the scroll is not working. Is there any code.?
Please help..
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the `onScrollStateChanged` method of the `OnScrollListener` class (most likely in conjunction with a touch listener) to detect changes in the `SCROLL_STATE` - when the list has stopped scrolling the state will change from a state that is not `SCROLL_STATE_IDLE` to `SCROLL_STATE_IDLE`.

When you state is not idle that time invisible your image in scrollview. and if your scrollivew in idle state then visible your image.

Comment: How to add that image in it

Comment: Simply add imageview at bottom of that scrollview.

Answer (score 1):

You can use FrameLayout with 2 views with the top view transperant and containing an image button with the arrow image in it. on button click increment the scroll and onScrollStateChanged change button visibility to false and when scroll is ideal set the button visibility to true. Y do you want such complexities instead of normal scrolling with hand

Comment: ok fine but the scroll inside the framelayout is not working @prvn

Comment: you should not set the scroll for frame layout you have to set it to the underlying view get the reference to that scroll object

Comment: could you please make it detail

Comment: But @prvn i want that arrow image over that scroll which shown in the image attached above.